# Getting error while replacing word using perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a script for replacing 2 words from a text file. The script is

```
count=1
for f in *.pdf
do
    filename="$(basename $f)"
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    filename="${filename//_/ }"
    echo $filename
    echo $f

    perl -pe 's/intime_mean_pu.pdf/'$f'/' fig.tex > fig_$count.tex
    perl -pi 's/TitleFrame/'$filename'/' fig_$count.tex

    sed -i '/Pointer-rk/r fig_'$count'.tex' $1.tex
    count=$((count+1))
done
```

But the replacing of words using the second perl command is giving error:

```
Can't open perl script "s/TitleFrame/Masses1/": No such file or directory
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: add the -x and -v to your bash invocation, and bash will tell you what it is running at each line of the bash script. You will be able to see is any of the variable substitutions are going wrong.   '#!/usr/bin/bash -xv' or bash -xv myscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your script to something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.pdf; do
    filename=$(basename "$f" .pdf)
    filename=${filename//_/}

    perl -spe 's/intime_mean_pu.pdf/$a/;
    s/TitleFrame/$b/' < fig.tex -- -a="$f" -b="$filename" > "fig_$count.tex"

    sed -i "/Pointer-rk/r fig_$count.tex" "$1.tex"
    ((++count))
done
```

As well as some other minor changes to your script, I have made use of the `-s` switch to Perl, which means that you can pass arguments to the one-liner. The bash variables have been double quoted to avoid problems with spaces in filenames, etc.

Alternatively, you could do the whole thing in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Basename;

my $file_arg = shift;
my $count = 1;

for my $f (glob "*.pdf") {
    my $name = fileparse($f, qq(.pdf));

    open my $in, "<", $file_arg;
    open my $out, ">", 'tmp';
    open my $fig, "<", 'fig.tex';    

    # copy up to match
    while (<$in>) {
        print $out $_;
        last if /Pointer-rk/;
    }

    # insert contents of figure (with substitutions)
    while (<$fig>) {
        s/intime_mean_pu.pdf/$f/;
        s/TitleFrame/$name/;
        print $out $_;
    }

    # copy rest of file
    print $out $_ while <$in>;

    rename 'tmp', $file_arg;
    ++$count;
}
```

Use the script like `perl script.pl "$1.tex"`.

Comment: I tried the first option but I am getting error saying :
basename: invalid option -- 's'

Comment: I guess that the option isn't portable. You can use what you had before instead

Comment: No problem. By the way I have just edited the `basename` command so it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the -e in the second perl call

Comment: when I am putting -e then it is giving following error :

Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.

Comment: @ramkrishna That could happen if `$filename` is set to ``foo\``, for example. It looks like you're calling `perl` and `sed` from inside a `bash` script; you will have a lot fewer issues with quoting if you do everything in pure Perl.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Perl all the things!